# Use a javascript function on the browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I would like to run the Javascript function "backPrev(-1)" if the back button of the browser is pressed
. Thank you

Comment: There's no way to know when the back button has been pressed, so this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onbeforeunload` [function](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm) to call `backPrev` function

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    backPrev(-1);
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This will occur **any** time the page is unloaded, even if you click a link to go to another page, for example.

Comment: Does that mean there is no standard way to detect it unless we do some hash things? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: There's no way to detect the back button at all

Comment: That worked, but unfortunately there is a message whether I really want to leave the page. Can you turn this message off?